# Can "the" be omitted here?

Tags: articles

In academic writing is it correct to say

> Access to services depends on individual circumstances, such as age, nature of the problem and urgency of required care

or

> Access to services depends on individual circumstances, such as the age, the nature of the problem and the urgency of required care

Comment: I would say "the" definitive article, as the second example, but "the age" is ambiguous - the age of the patient, of the problem, or of the knowledge?

Comment: No need for **the age** unless you say: **such as the age of the patient**. such as age, the nature of the problem and the urgency of care required. The is needed due to the "genitives".

Comment: First please note, *academic* as opposed to any other kind of writing doesn’t matter. An article is needed, or not.

Access to services does depend on individual circumstances but if you really think *the age* and *the nature of the problem* and *the urgency of required care* are comparable then please rephrase the example at least two different ways to prove that… One way, even?

Comment: Do you mean "the age of the problem" or "the age of the person"?  I suspect you mean the latter, in which case I would write "... such as **the patient's** age, **the nature of the problem**, and the urgency of **the situation**.  The "required care" is not - of itself - urgent: it is the **need** for care that is urgent!